# How to install JCloud Server Application in my own VPS and service for developers

Tags: java, linux, cloud, gcloud-compute

When i have my own linux VPS Server , how can i initial software environment and install JCloud Server Application to service for developers.

Answer (score 1):

**1 : Check JDK version in your server**

```
~$: java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

JDK version should be 1.7 or above

**2: Make sure you have proper J2EE container(tomcat/weblogic/resin..) installed in your server**

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.30
Server built:   Jul 19 2020 21:45:54 UTC
Server number:  9.0.30.0
OS Name:        Mac OS X
OS Version:     10.14.6
Architecture:   x86_64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_221-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
~$:
```

we are using Tomcat as our web application container , You ca use any J2EE container(resin/webLogic/GlassFish...) to host the war file.

**3: Install Mysql-Server in your server**

```
~$: mysql -ubigdog -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.7.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

create database in MYSQL :

```
CREATE DATABASE JCloudWeb;
```

Note: The database name above should be as same as "jdbc.url" attribute in step 4 below when you edit config file "WEB-INF/classes/conf/myconf.properties"

Create user credential in MYSQL

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Make sure your MYSQL-Server version is 5.7.27 or above. And create an account in mysql , we will use this account in next step. As a developer you need to have three thing when you finish current step:

```
 1: MYSQL host IP address/Domain
 2: MYSQL account access username 
 3: MYSQL account access password
```

Note: You should be able to access MYSQL Server from the host which is running JCloud web application using the account credential above.

**4: download JCloud server war file**

Go to JCloud official website to download JCloud server war file and deploy to tomcat. JCloud Server war file name format is:JCloudServer_1.0.1.war

unzip the war file using command below:

```
jar xvf JCloudServer.war 

or

unzip JCloudServer.war
```

This is the directory structure once you extract war file:

```
JCloudServer$: ls
META-INF    WEB-INF     index.jsp   res
JCloudServer$:
```

Edit database configuration information using command below:

```
vim WEB-INF/classes/conf/myconf.properties
```

in myconf.properties ,you should be able to see :jdbc.url,jdbc.user,jdbc.password, please fill correct value for each of them , you should get those values from step 3 above.

**5: config server.xml**

If you are using tomcat, then you can config as below, if you are using other J2EE container , please config your server correctly .

```
vim $TOMCAT/conf/server.xml
```

add the config below to proper postion

```
 <Context path="/" docBase="/opt/webapp/JCloudServer/"/>
```

***docBase*** is the absolute directory of JCloud web app , ***path*** is the URI which you want to expose your app to internet .

**6: Start tomcat server to run JCloud Server war file**

```
catalina.sh start
```

Now you should be able to see JCloud Server by accessing http://localhost-ip-domain:port/ to see home page , you can share the access domain to your developers so that they can register their own developer account in your JCloud server.

Once developers get the account in JCloud server, they can download JCloud SDK to develop native/web apps based on JCloud framework .

Here is the link about how to use JCloud SDK : [How can i use JCloud SDK API to communicate with JCloud Server application for app(native/web) development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037755)